# I have a 2d grid of size n * 10(the rows are defined by user input). How can I store multiple strings in same location in a 2d vector

Tags: c++

This is a C++ game that I just started to work on and is based on plants vs zombies.
Let's say the user requested a 4 * 10 grid and I have set up my grid like this at the beginning of the game:

```
*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*
|  Q  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | BH  |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*
|  Q  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | BH  |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*
|  Q  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | BH  |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*
|  Q  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | BH  |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*
```

Now, I want to add a new zombie 'Z', let's say in location [2][9] (as seen below the BH), and will start moving the zombie 'Z' each turn (one to the left).

```
*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*
|  Q  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | BH  |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*
|  Q  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | BH  |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*
|  Q  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | BH  |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |  Z  |
*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*
|  Q  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | BH  |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*-----*
```

Here is the function where I fill the Square with "Q" and "BH":

```
void Game::fill_square_with_Q_and_BH(int numrows){

   room.resize(numrows);

    for(int i = 0; i < numrows; i++){
            room[i].resize(10);
    }
    //fill rows with Q
    for(int i = 0; i < numrows; i++){
        room[i][0].set_fill_square("Q     ");
    }

        //fill rows with BH
    for(int i = 0; i < numrows; i++){
        room[i][9].set_fill_square("    BH");
    }
}
```

This is how I built my 2d grid with the following functions:

```
void Game::innerlines(int tab){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < tab; i ++){
        cout << "|" << "      ";
    }
    cout << "|" << endl;

    for(int k = 0; k < tab ; k++){
        cout << "*" << "------";
    }
    cout << "*" << endl;
}
```

And another function like:

```
void Game::create_n_table()
{

    cout << endl;
    
    for(int k = 0; k < 10 ; k++){
        cout << "*" << "------";
    }
    cout << "*" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(int l = 0; l < 10; l++){
     //here I replace the "      " with a vector<vector<Square>> room;
        //so, instead below I have something like room[i][l].fill_square();
                cout << "|" << "      ";
        }  
        cout << "|" << endl;
        innerlines(10);
    }
```

I don't know how to approach this because each Zombie will receive different damage from each different plant that I place on a square.
I know that if insert the string "Z" in my 2d vector where the "BH" is located, it will be replaced with the "Z" string. Also, what is if I want to insert more than 2 zombies in the same location where the 'BH' sits? How can I possibly display them all in the same location? could it be one below the other?
Any thoughts would be appreciated! Thank you beforehand.

Comment: If there is a limit of like 10 or less chars per cell (element), then just use a 3D array of `char` as `char board[rows][cols][maxchars]`. It will be many many time more efficient than using a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` for a few characters. However, if you have an unknown board size and unknown number of characters, then let `std::vector` and `std::string` worry about the memory management for you.

Comment: For example with `std::string foo{};`, then `foo = foo + "hello" + " world";` is valid while `foo += "hello" + " world";` is not -- the first term is not `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to have the 2D vector of `std::string` instead of `char`.

This way when you want to add a lets say zombie at location [2][9] for example then you could write

```
vec[2][9]+="Z"; //or vec[2][9]+="\nZ"
```

Similarly when you want to remove a zombie you could use `std::string::erase`.

Comment: that sounds good. However, it is not working the way it should be because I have my square grids filled with empty strings "     " and when I add another string("Z") to my "  BH  " string, it messes with the square grid spaces.

Comment: @vmilk- You didn't give any code by which we/i can see what you're actually doing. You only gave us an idea of what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve. So i also gave an idea to solve your problem. Unless you show us any working code we couldn't help you. Add your header and source files so that we can better understand what you're currently doing and how it can be improved. Without that how can we answer your question(since the question has incomplete information). You said you want to display one below other, which you can do using `vec[2][9]+="\nZ";` as i suggested.

Comment: sorry about that. I just updated my question based on some changes.

Comment: In order to use `+` (concatenation) on strings, the string must begin with `std::string` and NOT a String Literal. If you have `""` you can construct a string instead with `std::string{""}`. Then you can concatenate.