# vector of pointers and checking events of each indexes

Tags: c++

**EDITED**

I'm currently working on a c++ assignment and I'm trying to simulate the game plants vs zombies.

Here is a brief description of the game.

Five things happen each turn:

1. A Zombie is generated on the right side of the board, i.e., at square 10.
2. The player can generate an ant and place it anywhere on the board. Note: The player may choose not to generate a plant if they don’t want to or have insufficient food. The plants attack the zombies.
3. The Zombies either attack a plant(order of attack is left to right) which is blocking them or pass through to the next square on the board if they are not blocked by an ant.
4. If the zombies have reached square 1 or if there are any zombies left in play, declare a winner, and end the game if either condition is true. Note: plants win by killing all the zombies on the board, including the newly generated one from step 1 in the same turn.

Ants action each turn if generated in board:
Long_thrower plant has a food cost of 2 and an armor of 3 and inflicts one damage to the zombies which is closest but at least 3 squares away.
potato plant has a food cost of 4 and an armor of 4. can't attack but potatoes block zombies from stepping in until are killed.

Zombies action:
Each zombie has an armor of 3 and inflicts one damage to each plant one square away and can't step in a plant square until the plant is killed.
//many others.

I have already set up the 8x 10 2d grid where the game will take place.
I have a plant base class with 7 derived classes as well as a zombie base class with 3 derived classes. I also have a square class and a game class. I have the following files below.

Here is my square.h file

```
class Square{
    protected:
        vector<Plants* > types;
        vector<Zombies* > zmbie;
        int num_types;
        //many others
```

Game.h file

```
class Game{
    protected:
        bool gameover;
        int foodbank;
        vector<vector<Square> >room;
    public:
        Game();
        //many others
```

Now, I was able to store ants and zombies in the 2d vector of Square under my game.CPP. Here is how I set and call each ant from my square.cpp to my game.cpp

```
void Square::set_plant_to_board(int choice){

    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            types.push_back(new Bodyguard());
            break;
        case 2:
            types.push_back(new Long_thrower());
            break;
        //many others
```

```
string Square::get_plant(){

    return types[num_types - 1]->get_plant_type();

}
```

And in my game.CPP I do this to store the plant in my 2d grid:

```
room[i][l].set_plant_to_board(user_choice);
room[I][l].get_plant();
```

Now, I'm struggling with how to deal with each plant and zombie action. In the game, during each turn, each plant causes different times of point damage to a zombie and vice-versa and they also have different types of abilities(such as armor).

So, I think a good approach may be keeping track of each zombie and plant but I don't know how to do that. Luckily, there can be only one plant at each square, but there can be many zombies at each square. So, how can I keep track of them?. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you, beforehand!

Comment: Can you edit your question with a list of actions that the various plants/zombies can do? Not everyone has intimate knowledge of that game. I can imagine that most plant actions will only affect the first zombie in line of sight, while others may have piercing effects or throw projectiles at an arc. I presume zombies move forward and may damage plants as an action?

Comment: Maybe keep a map of the game entities and their corresponding square location, or vice-versa depending on how you intend to keep track?

Comment: As a simple hint to get you unstuck, I suggest looping over every square and telling each plant to run a polymorphic `act(int row, int column, Game& game)` function. This allows each plant to see if there are zombies in its firing arcs and do damage to the zombies. Vice versa, zombies should probably have a simple state machine that is either "eat plant in front of me" or "get closer to plants"

Comment: Each square in your game has a vector of Zombie pointers, so to manipulate the list of zombies you will be using typical `std::vector<>` methods. To add a new zombie `room[i][l].zmbie.push_back(new Zombie());` and to loop through the zombies: `for (auto z: room[i][l].zmbie) { z->someMethod(); }`

Comment: If a square can only contain one plant, why does it have a vector of plants? (And why are the plants called "types", and the zombies "zmbie"? Names are important.)

Comment: You could've just added this description in your last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70029870/i-have-a-2d-grid-of-size-n-10the-rows-are-defined-by-user-input-how-can-i-s) instead of asking a new question.

Comment: @Anoop Rana, I thought I would confuse others since my current question is different.

Comment: Sorry for the poor description. I just edited. I'm thinking about something like this: void Square::add_ant(Plant* a) {
  this->plant_array.push_back(a);
|

Comment: @AnoopRana Be careful with your recommendations, you could accidentally trigger OP to turn the question which you have answered into a moving target (i.e. edit the question so that your answer is invalidated...).

Comment: @Yunnosch Read carefully, i said "added this description" and not "replacing the old question completely with this new one". My point is that the old question or the new(this) one should be more clear/specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of what your game loop might look like:

```
void Game::update() {
  // 1. Spawn a zombie
  int zombie_row = random_number(0, 8);
  room[zombie_row][9].add_zombie(new_random_zombie());

  // 2. Generate a plant
  foodbank += 1; // TODO: vary food supply?
  ask_and_plant_plant(); // TODO: ask player for what plant to place and where

  // 3. Zombies attack plants
  for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
      for (Zombie * z: room[r][c].get_zombies()) {
        // Special case: if we have a zombie on column 0, the game is over.
        // We entered this loop so there is at least one zombie on column 0.
        if (c == 0) {
          gameover = true;
          return;
        }
        z->act(r, c, this);
      }
    }
  }

  // 4. Plants attack zombies
  for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
      for (Plant* p : room[r][c].get_plants()) {
        p->act(r, c, this);
      }
    }
  }

  // 5. Check for victory condition: no more zombies
  if (no_more_zombies()) {
    gameover = true;
  }
}
```

Now, for every zombie type and plant type, implement a polymorphic

```
void act(int r, int c, Game* g);
```

That implements the behavior for every variant.
For example:

```
void Long_thrower::act(int r, int c, Game* g) {
  for (c = c + 3; c < 10; c++) {
    Square& sq = g->get_square(r, c);
    auto& zombies = sq.get_zombies();
    if (!zombies.empty()) {
      bool dead = zombies.first().receive_damage(1);
      if (dead) {
        zombies.erase(zombies.begin());
      }
      return; // Stop damaging zombies after the first hit.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! Your explanation makes sense. I’ll implement something like that.